# JSON deserialization using reflection

Tags: scala, lift-json

Hi I am trying to extract a JSON using reflection

```
import net.liftweb.json._
case class Bike(make: String, price: Int) {
   def this(price: Int) = this("Trek", price)
}

val cls = Class.forName("Bike")
val manifest = Manifest.classType(cls)
val parsedData =net.liftweb.json.JsonParser.parse(json)

JsonParser.parse(""" {"price":350} """).extract[manifest]
```

however I am getting this error:

```
not found: type manifest
  JsonParser.parse(""" {"price":350} """).extract[manifest]
                                                   ^
```

although manifest is from type Manifest

Comment: Thanks ...changed to deserialization:) how can I ignore the manifest it needs to extract to specific type

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can extract directly into a `case class`

```
val json = "the json";

val bike = parse(json).extract[Bike];
```

JSON parsing is done through reflection.

If the class is a runtime construct, create a [**TypeInfo**](http://liftweb.net/api/25/api/#net.liftweb.json.TypeInfo) instance and pass that to the extract method.

Answer (score 1):

There is a variation of the `extract()` method that might work for you, if you provide it with a `TypeInfo` instance.

See here: https://github.com/lift/lift/blob/master/framework/lift-base/lift-json/src/main/scala/net/liftweb/json/Extraction.scala#L178